# Tkinter widgets

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, output

```
Directory: C:\Users\User\Documents
20.jpg       77fg45174161873c84172b66ba4
```

I would like to place the results above within the canvas widget where I have placed the text *"MD5 File Hashes"*, the following is being placed within the `centerLabel` panel. However, it needs to be placed within the canvas.

The following code is fully functioning, but not displaying it with the results intended:

```
Label['text'] = output
canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, text="Hashes")
```

Comment: You may want to change your `Canvas` parent (`Canvas(centerLabel, ...)`) to `root` as in `Canvas(root, ...)`. Right now label is the parent, which looks redundant.

Comment: for some reason the directory is not displaying Directory: C:\Users\Ghost\Documents\MalwareTest

Comment: It's not being displayed, because it's never been asked to. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, text="MD5 File Hashes")
```

with:

```
canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, text=output)
```

if you want to display `rootDir` as well you can instead replace with:

```
canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, text="Directory: {}\n{}".format(rootDir, output))
```

The `output` you have is a string:

```
>>>type(output)
<class 'str'>
```

So you can easily put it on as any place that accepts strings, such as `print(output)` and `canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, text=output)`.

Comment: How would i also place the subdirList within that line, i have tried: canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, text="Directory: {}\n{}/n{}".format(rootDir, subdirList, output)) but i am getting [] as an answer

Comment: What does `type(subdirList)` return?

Comment: the sub directory that bit is working but not when i try to put it into the canvas

Comment: @KXA.Pytho3 I don't think that answers my question.

Comment: apologies let me rephrase> i also want to add the subdirList into that line canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, text="Directory: {}\n{}".format(rootDir, output))

Comment: That's a separate question which I can't really answer here.